# I reported an error during contract interaction

Tags: 0x

This is my method of obtaining the signer

async function getSigner() {
if (window.ethereum) {
await window.ethereum.enable()
provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
// console.log(window.ethereum)
console.log(provider)
const signer = provider.getSigner()
console.log(signer)
setSigner(signer)
const contract = new ethers.Contract(daiAddress, daiAbi, provider)
console.log(contract)
setDaiContract(contract)
}
}

Error: sending a transaction requires a signer (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.7.0)

Comment: async function getSigner() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      await window.ethereum.enable()
      provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
      // console.log(window.ethereum)
      console.log(provider)
      const signer = provider.getSigner()
      console.log(signer)
      setSigner(signer)
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(daiAddress, daiAbi, provider)
      console.log(contract)
      setDaiContract(contract)
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

The provider can be used only for viewing, and the signer is required if the contract state variables need to be modified.

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(daiAddress, daiAbi, signer)
```